# Can I set cassandra cluster with vnode using in one datacenter and another not

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I had a cassandra cluster with one datacenter and it is upgraded from 1.0.7 to 2.1.8. However, the old datacenter does not use vnode settings because the  1.0.7 does not support it.

Right now, I want to add a new datacenter of 2.1.8 version and want to use vnode settings in the new data center. Can I keep the old datacenter not using vnode and the new datacenter with vnode settings?

Comment: You cannot have a 2.1 and 1.0 DC in the same cluster. You need to take the regular upgrade path for 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the procedure listed [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configVnodesProduction_t.html).

"You cannot directly convert a single-token nodes to a vnode. However, you can configure another data center configured with vnodes already enabled and let Cassandra automatic mechanisms distribute the existing data into the new nodes. This method has the least impact on performance."